# Guide to use valgrind with wine

Tags: linux, debugging, memory-leaks, valgrind, wine

Requirement: Remove memory-leaks for windows application(x86 and x64) by using wine and valgrind.

After lot of seraching on net and also looking into official page for this [Valgrind and wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_and_Valgrind), i am still unable to fine proper steps/ guide to this.

Constaraints involved :
1. OS type (Centos, RHEL... I am using UBUNTU 17.10 X64)
2. Architecture for host system (x86 and x64)
3. Wine builds (32 bit, 64 build and multi-arch)
4. Execution 32 bit/64 bit windows app
5. Missing DLLs issue

eg - I compiled a simple debug exe on VS 2008 and tried to memcheck it but it didn't work and asks for dlls MSVCP90D.dll and MSVCR90D.dll, while they are already installed in wine !

Anyone can help on this please ?

Comment: Why this strange requirement? Have you looked [here](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_and_Valgrind)?

Comment: This is not a guide. It just a warmup tips for this arrangement. And yes it is not working properly. I am refining question again.

Comment: From what I can tell valgrind doesn't include MSVCP90D.dll and MSVCR90D.dll, only the non-debug versions MSVCP90.dll and MSVCR90.dll.

Comment: Is there any other to make it work ?

Comment: You could use a release build with debug information.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about this ?

Comment: See [How to: Debug a Release Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx). This build would use the non-debug CRT dlls, but still include the debug info necessary for the stacktrace of the leaks.